# c# Accessing a row in a 2-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, rows, multidimensional-array

How do I access a row of a 2-dimensional array in C#? I want to get the count of row i.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good resource: > [http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array)

Comment: I know this is old, but the link has changed. I guess this is why you don't just post a url. https://www.dotnetperls.com/2d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question really depends on what type of 2D array you are thinking about and what dimension your row is.

**Proper 2D array**

```
// Init
var arr = new int[5,10];

// Counts
arr.GetLength(0) // Length of first dimension: 5
arr.GetLength(1) // Length of second dimension: 10
```

**Jagged "2D" array**

```
// Init
var arr = new int[3][];
// Initially arr[0],arr[1],arr[2] is null, so we have to intialize them:
arr[0] = new int[5];
arr[1] = new int[4];
arr[2] = new int[2];

// Counts
arr.Length // Length of first dimension
// In this case the "second dimension" (if you can call it that) is of variable size
arr[0].Length // Length: 5
arr[1].Length // Length: 4
arr[2].Length // Length: 2
```

Comment: Thanks, 2d arrays are a lot different in C#

Answer (score 0):

This will also work,

```
string[,] a = new string[,]
{
    {"ant", "aunt"},
    {"Sam", "Samantha"},
    {"clozapine", "quetiapine"},
    {"flomax", "volmax"},
    {"toradol", "tramadol"}
};

// a[1,1] is equal to Samantha
```